# Workflow that sends out a notification to archive vs. delete the document

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, workflow

I am setting up a retention policy against a document library that will run a workflow that will notify the admin to either delete or archive the document after x number of days.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the Workflow when the item is **Created**
2. Use the following Actions in your Workflow:

   - Pause for Duration (specify x days there)
   - Send an Email (specify Admins group and notification text)

[image: List Workflow]

Comment: that is stage 1. What about the archive or delete option in the email?

Comment: Add "Start a task Process" action instead of Email Users. Create a new Task Content Type with "Archive", "Delete" and "Keep" options and specify this new  Content Type as Task Content Type in Outcome Options of Task Process. So Admins walk through the Approval process and decide what to do. Regarding on their choice the Workflow should  perform the action "Delete Item" or "Copy Document" to some "Archive" library and then "Delete Item". In case the Admins clicked "Keep" option, the Workflow should get completed without any actions. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I wanted. Can you please provide a screenshot of the workflow if possible? The workflow will run once the retention policy ion the documnet library is processed (after x number of days)

Comment: both functions must be available from the email notification

Answer (score 0):

can also use Microsoft Flow if thats easier which I think it is